# OpenCV img.shape returning incorrect dimensions

Tags: python, opencv

I am loading an image and getting dimensions in Python OpenCV like this...

```
img = cv2.imread(filepath)

height, width = srcImg.shape

print("width %s" % width)
print("height %s" % height)
```

The image I am loading is 800x600 but shape reports it as 64x480

Anyone any ideas why?

Comment: Are you working with binary image? If not, `img.shape` returns three values, `height`, `width`, and `channels`

Answer (score 1):

I think you are getting dimensions of the wrong image, here `srcImg` instead of `img`.

Try this:

```py
img = cv2.imread(filepath)

height, width = img.shape[:2]

print("width %s" % width)
print("height %s" % height)
```

Answer (score 1):

try this , this will work for normal image formats

```
img = cv2.imread(filepath)
height,width=img.shape[0],img.shape[1]
print(height,width)
```

Hope this will help you